# What are the units of QPdfDocument::pageSize?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine, qt5.15

[`QPdfDocument` (5.15.2)](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.15/qpdfdocument-members.html), in the *QtPDF* module (part of *QtWebEngine*), seems to not be fully documented yet (presumably because it's fairly new, first appearing in 5.14).

What are the units of the size returned by `QPdfDocument::pageSize()` (don't bother checking those docs, it's not there)?

It appears to be some reasonable (albeit seemingly low-res) pixel-like units except I'm not sure how it is deducing the document's DPI. Also I've only tested on a limited set of PDF's all generated from the same source, so I'm not sure how normal my observations are, especially given it's a `QSizeF` rather than a `QSize` (which raises the possibility of e.g. other non-pixel units in other as-of-yet unencountered contexts).

Ultimately what I'd like to do is get the page size of a loaded document's page in physical units (e.g. inches) then determine a rendered output size in pixels given a user-specified DPI.

---

An example of the values I've observed:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtPdf>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QUrl url("http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");
    QNetworkAccessManager internet;
    QNetworkReply *reply = internet.get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [reply] () {
        QPdfDocument pdf;
        pdf.load(reply);
        qDebug() << reply->url() << ":";
        for (int k = 0; k < pdf.pageCount(); ++ k)
            qDebug() << k << pdf.pageSize(k);
        QCoreApplication::exit();
    });

    return app.exec();

}
```

Outputs:

```
QUrl("http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf") :
0 QSizeF(595, 842)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [implementation](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/pdf/qpdfdocument.cpp) is done with PDFium. Qt calls FPDF_GetPageSizeByIndex and the [docs](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/refs/heads/master/public/fpdfview.h) state the height/width is in points:

```
// Function: FPDF_GetPageSizeByIndex
//          Get the size of the page at the given index.
// Parameters:
//          document    -   Handle to document. Returned by FPDF_LoadDocument.
//          page_index  -   Page index, zero for the first page.
//          width       -   Pointer to a double to receive the page width
//                          (in points).
//          height      -   Pointer to a double to receive the page height
//                          (in points).
// Return value:
//          Non-zero for success. 0 for error (document or page not found).
// Note:
//          Prefer FPDF_GetPageSizeByIndexF() above. This will be deprecated in
//          the future.
FPDF_EXPORT int FPDF_CALLCONV FPDF_GetPageSizeByIndex(FPDF_DOCUMENT document,
                                                      int page_index,
                                                      double* width,
                                                      double* height);
```

This is also noted in the [PDFium SDK manual](https://pdfium.patagames.com/help/html/M_Patagames_Pdf_Pdfium_FPDF_GetPageSizeByIndex.htm).